# Power problems with Droid Incredible 2

Tags: battery, charging, power-on, htc-droid-incredible-2

My daughter's Droid Incredible 2 is *mostly* dead.

Symptoms:

- If we can manage to turn it on, it only stays on for a minute or so after it completes all of its start-up tasks. Then turns off and acts like the battery is dead.
- When I plug it in, I usually get a rapidly flashing amber light, rather than the steady amber light (for charging) that I would expect. Usually the flashing seems to slow down and then stop (with the light off). There's no indication that it's charging.

There's no water damage, nor is there any physical damage to speak of. (Just some less-than-normal wear-and-tear.)

I've removed the battery and checked the contacts. They're nice, shiny metal. The battery is seated properly.

Have I got a battery that needs replacing? Does it just need to charge longer before turning on? (I am seeing the same issue with two different phone chargers, including one for my Galaxy Nexus that has no issues.)

Any insights?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Incredible 2 has a defective charging port that does not typically last a long time. It is an extremely common issue with this phone. Chances are, this is what you are seeing.

Disclaimer: I have been using my current dinc2 for ~18 months and haven't had this issue yet, but I did see it on a used phone I attempted to buy. Anyway, my plan for if/when this does happen is:

[Repair HTC Incredible 2 USB Charge Port](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z7l6mnquPbg)

The part is supposed to be $12 and takes an hour to do. If you're not comfortable doing it yourself, I'd take it to a cell phone repair shop.

Comment: Well, my wife pays a stupid amount of money for a service plan, so I brought it in for repair.